# Installing 3 Bulb Chandelier

Tags: electrical, light-fixture, ceiling

[image: Ceiling and Light Fixture Wires]

[image: 2 Additional Wires]

**This used chandelier came with 3L, 3N & 3E wires, plus 2 spare wires, one marked with electrical tape. Which wires should I attach to the spares, and where do I attach the 3 Earth Wires?**

Comment: Can you get us photos of the inside of the switch box that controls this light please?

Answer (score 1):

Earth wire are grounds.  The N= Neutral or white  L= hot or load and go to the black wire.

Normally the wires to the lightbulbs are all tied to a pigtail for each  Hot, neutral and ground.  The spare, or seperate wires were probably the pigtails for the neutral and hot (electrical tape). All grounds/ earths get tied together.

Comment: I would like to know how the switch is wired up first.